# Best practice for creating a public site and private admin site using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture

If I am creating a Ruby on Rails app consisting of a public web site and a private administration web site, what is the best practice for doing this in Ruby on Rails?

I want to make sure I am sticking with the DRY principle and avoid duplicating functionality such as CRUD operations.  The most logical solution I've come across is to create RESTful services to handle these tasks and use ActiveResource to utilize them from the web sites.

Is this the best approach?  If not, what should I be considering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

the using of activeresource can be more complicated that if you don't using. because the problem if you want avoid some code duplicate is the controller.

You want two different website 1 in front and a second one in backend so each of them have no the same view.

You request on Database are the same between your front and backend, so there are no problem of code duplicate. You can use it in both part.

The only part where you can have some code duplicate is the controller. But in this case, you need add some authorisation rules or don't have the same route than so the code duplicate is really little.

So to me you just need code 2 website with the most little part of controller to avoid in maximun the code duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  How would you share, say, the Model code between the two apps?  Plugins?  Gems?

Comment: made only one app :) instead you can put all of your model in a gem. I already do.